# How do I release from Azure DevOps to a server via FTP?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops

I'm really new to ADO. I have a Git repro for an ASP.NET Core web site, and having set up a build, am trying to work out how to deploy the site to my hosting server via FTP.

I looked at [the MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops), but what they show there bears very little resemblance to what I see in my browser...

[image: New pipeline]

I tried the "IIS website and SQL database deployment" template, as that looked the most likely, but then got stuck at the next stage. I need to fill in some settings for the three tasks that it created, but it looks like this is for publishing direct to IIS, whereas I want to FTP the files to the server.

I then tried creating a blank release, and adding an FTP upload task to it. This looked more promising, but I couldn't work out how to run it. It doesn't fire after a successful build, and I can't see any option to run it manually.

The pipeline shows that it doesn't have a schedule set...

[image: pipeline]

...but I can't see where to set one, or if I even need one as I want to run after a build, not to a timed schedule.

Can anyone tell me how I'm supposed to do this? I just want it so that it will copy the deployment files to the server after a successful build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want a scheduled releases - click on the clock icon that you highlighted on the screenshot, if you want builds after releases click on the lightning icon that's a little higher than the clock icon and pick the trigger(s) you are interested in.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops

Comment: OK, so that is a food start, I had the CD trigger off. I enabled it, and now it is doing something, but it's uploading a zip file of the site, rather than the actual files themselves. Any idea how I get it to upload the files? Thanks for the help.

Comment: i dont know what task you are using exactly. i suggest you accept this answer and start a new one, since they are not really connected