# How do I create a build pipeline using TFS/GIT that will deploy to non Azure ftp?

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, ftp

I want to create a build pipeline so that when I check-in to tfs-git the built app will deploy over ftp.

The ftp site IS NOT on Azure, I have my own external host.

My pipeline builds the app successfully but now I need to deploy it to an external FTP site.

I've been trying for a while now and I can find no instructions or details to do this can anyone help?

Can anyone point me to some articles that will help me?

I want to

1. Push To Git
   (Done)
2. Trigger the build
   (Done)
3. Create the publish files
   (No idea)
4. Copy the publish files to my FTP (Non Azure)
   (Ftp works but can't see how to select the publish directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked it out
the **publish** arguments needs to have '--' preceding the parameter
also beware of ‘ and ’ curly single quotes if you copy and paste commands

```
# ASP.NET Core
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True

- task: FtpUpload@2
  displayName: 'FTP Upload'
  inputs:
      credentialsOption: inputs
      serverUrl: 'xxxxxxxx'
      username: 'xxxxxx'
      password: 'xxxxxxxx'
      remoteDirectory: '/'
      trustSSL: true
      cleanContents: true
      rootDirectory: $(Build.artifactstagingdirectory)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [**FTP Upload task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload?view=azure-devops) which you could use this task to upload files to a remote machine using the File Transfer Protocol (FTP), or securely with FTPS..

You could choose to publish build generated artifacts to Azure DevOps Server side drop folder, then use a release pipeline to upload them to remote ftp server.

Suggest you take a look at this step-by-step tutorial: [Use FTPS to deploy your WebApp using Azure DevOps](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2019/07/06/use-ftps-to-deploy-your-webapp-using-azure-devops/)

You could also take a look at below similar questions：

- [How do I release from Azure DevOps to a server via FTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56212576/how-do-i-release-from-azure-devops-to-a-server-via-ftp)
- [How to publish asp.net website using AzureDevOps in ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61615102/how-to-publish-asp-net-website-using-azuredevops-in-ftp)

To make sure the connection between your remote FTP sever and Azure DevOps build/release agent, please pay attention to below part:

> The Microsoft Hosted IP address is dynamic. You need to download the
> weekly JSON file and add IP ranges to your server.
>
> More information, please refer to: [To identify the possible IP ranges
> for Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#to-identify-the-possible-ip-ranges-for-microsoft-hosted-agents)

For your scenario, I’d suggest that you could setup a [self-hosted/private agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops), then do build/release on this agent. With this way, you just need to add that agent machine’s IP to your server.

Comment: Well, I'm still digging, like wading through treacle. I've got the ftp task working, my problem now is to get the pipeline to build and publish and then get the ftp task to use the content of the publish directory.

Comment: The FTP article assumes I am publishing to Azure storage which I am not)